# How to write a regex in java

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "123 876 644";
        String str2 = "123 876 644 345";

        // how to write pattern ?
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("123 876 644");

        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("aa");
        }

        Matcher m2 = pattern.matcher(str2);
        if (m2.find()) {
            System.out.println("bb");
        }

    }
}
```

I want to println aa, and don't want to println bb here.
What should I write pattern `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("123 876 644");`

some one can help me, please.

Comment: You mean `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^123 876 644$");`

Comment: when you want to print aa? when your string matches exactly with pattern or when it contains pattern?

Comment: Is it possible that you intended to use Matcher#matches instead of Matcher#find ?

Comment: @YCF_L  It's right, I didn't find ^ and $ before. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The Pattern "123 876 644" exists in both str and str2 hence it would print both 'aa' and 'bb'. When executing Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile() try using it with a regular expression that dosen't exist in str2 but does in str.
If you assign 
    str = 123 876 644 345;
    str2 = 123 876 6644;
and then use
    Patter.compile("123 876 644")
only println bb executes.